# Where does Chrome store the "Recently closed tabs" file in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, browser

I need to know where Chrome stores the "Recently closed tabs" file in Mac OS X.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/610281/how-to-restore-chromes-list-of-recently-closed-tabs

Comment: I don't think they're only stored in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Last\ Tabs and ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Current\ Tabs, because if you try to lock them, Recently closed tabs will be created anyway.

Comment: ok, well it was just a guess, the question looked similar so I commented it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely within the following folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

There is a file within that folder called `Current Tabs` that is among the last files written to when you quit Chrome, but it is in binary, so good luck parsing it.

Comment: Ok. But why even if I made it non-writable, Recently closed tabs will be created anyway? If you lock the History file, Chrome doesn't save your browsing History.

Comment: I don't know the interior workings of Chrome, but pointed you in the direction of where they would most likely be stored.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to not store any Recently closed tab, just like what I accomplished with the browsing history by locking the History file.

Comment: I see.  That looks like it might be a difficult one as a number of people have complained about the new Tab Page since it's release in v33.  If you're feeling adventurous, you might try browsing through this list of flags via `chrome://flags/`. Or just continue to experiment with the files in the Application Support folder. Good luck.

Comment: How do I find older versions of tabs? For example, when I opened Chrome and the tabs weren't there. I opened a few more help forum tabs, etc. and I want to get back to the version like 3 sessions ago. Where would I find that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it here on a Mac:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Current\ Tabs\
```

Answer (score 0):

In home//.config/google-chrome/Default you'll find Current Session and Current Tabs. 
Scenario for me was replacing my system hard drive and, in the process, going from Mint to Ubuntu with Budgie! The old hard drive was available to copy things like Thunderbird mail files. 
Current Tabs for me had just a few entries in 19 kB, but Current Session had all the URLs for all the tabs I had had open when closing Chrome - around 100 !
Warning: It's not particularly Human-friendly! I got best results when using my favourite text editor - Ultra Edit.
Good luck!!